# beautifulsoup extracts only first 10 elements

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Im trying to extract information from Volkswagen page on kununu. For example "Pro" information.

```
url = 'https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare'
page = requests.get(url)

soup = bs(page.text, 'html.parser')
divs = soup.find_all(class_="col-xs-12 col-lg-12")

for h2 in soup.find_all('h2', class_='h3', text=['Pro']):
    print(h2.find_next_sibling('p').get_text())
```

But as an output I have only first 10 "Pro".
Looks like that it shows only top 10 commentaries by default, however all unvisible comments are under "col-xs-12 col-lg-12" class... Or maybe Im missing something
Can you help me extract all data, not just first 10?

Comment: Because you need to click to keep scraping, you're entering the realms of dynamic html, so you'll need to also use `selenium` and download a webdriver.

Comment: @JuanC kindly take my opinion friendly. you don't need to tell user that `you need` as maybe there's other solution. i think you can tell `maybe you can use selenium AFAIK`

Comment: That right, I didn't know about @alecxe's option. Now I can't edit, but thanks for your input ahmed

Comment: @JuanC you welcome :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can load these comments *mimicking the XHR requests* a browser is sending to load more comments dynamically.

Working code (note: uses f-strings, so 3.6+; use `.format()` if using an earlier Python version):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


comments = []
with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = {
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
    }

    page = 1
    while True:
        print(f"Processing page {page}..")

        url = f'https://www.kununu.com/de/volkswagen/kommentare/{page}'
        response = session.get(url)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        new_comments = [
            pro.find_next_sibling('p').get_text()
            for pro in soup.find_all('h2', text='Pro')
        ]
        if not new_comments:
            print(f"No more comments. Page: {page}")
            break

        comments += new_comments

        # just to see current progress so far
        print(comments)
        print(len(comments))

        page += 1

print(comments)
```

Note how we instantiated and used `requests.Session()` object which [provides performance benefits](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) when sending multiple requests to the same host.

Comment: I learnt something new with your answer, but I have a couple doubts: where do you get this info about XHR requests, and how did you get to know you could write `.../kommentare/2`. Is this something you can see in the inspection tool?

Comment: @JuanC using browser `dev-tools` and `network-tab` you can check how the response retrieved from `XHR`. so we will keep the session and keep loping over it.

Comment: Thanks again ahmed, I was able to find it. Good to know there's other ways to achieve it without `selenium`